# Request library Post Request taking empty data for post

Tags: robotframework

I am posting a request using post request method but the log is showing it is taking empty data due to which action is not being perfomed

```
 ${auth}=  Create List  username   password
 &{key}=    Create Dictionary     prokey=Key:uiuij343jhkjk
Create Session    alias    uri   auth=${auth}    disable_warnings=true
${response}=    POST Request    alias    ${delete_uri}    data=${key}
```

logs show:
Post Request using : alias=alias, uri=******,  data=empty, headers=None, files=None, allow_redirects=True
        INFO    ${response} = Response [200]

Note:
data type is form-data

any help appreciated , how would i pass data to the post request.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete code example. Presently this doesn't provide enough information on what is actually in your variables.

Comment: i have edited the variable to the value i am passing , uri can not be shown.  . If any more information required let me know

Comment: Have you tried the examples in the test case scenario: https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/blob/master/tests/testcase.txt